# How to get User data (name,image) in firebase authentication with facebook?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I create login page where user can login through facebook successfully but I only get user email and userid in firebase.
The thing I want is username, profile image, etc.

(Edited)

Answer (score 0):

You can't get anyone's password through Firebase Authentication.  That would be a huge security hole, wouldn't it?  Profile image should be available, if the user provided one through Facebook.

Comment: Instead of password. How can i get user image if it available and User name.